# How To Pass Dynamic row and Section Array to numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, iphone, uitableview

I am facing this issue from many days. Anyone please sort-out this issue.

Below is my rows array, which count should pass in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

```
    (
        (
        "Service Speed",
        "Good Service",
        "Confirmation quality",
        "Quick Service in Reservation"
    ),
        (
        "Check In",
        "Happy on their Service",
        Courtesey,
        "Quick Service at Checkin"
    ),
        (
        "Front office & reception",
        "Overall Quality of Room",
        Check,
        "Response time"
    ),
        (
        "Room Decor",
        "Time taken to serveTime taken to serveTime taken t",
        Bathroom,
        "Facilities in the Room",
        "Choice of menu",
        Housekeeping,
        "Room Service"
    ),
        (
        "Overall Comments",
        "Will you come back again"
    ),
    "Guest Satisfaction Ratings"
  )
```

My question is, how to pass row array count in `numberOfRowsInSection` and array values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

I tried using below code but I am getting Error:

> "[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [GroupName count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [GroupName objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[RowsArr objectAtIndex:section] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.Label.text = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Problem is in the last object of array 
"Guest Satisfaction Ratings",
 Because it comes in NSString so only its showing Error.

Comment: Put `"Guest Satisfaction Ratings"` into array with single object. It is corrected by api server side not by you.

Comment: ok,sure.Thanks for Suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sh_Khan is on the right track. Your problem is with the line:

```
[[RowsArr objectAtIndex:section] count];
```

You'll need to determine the type of the object you're getting, using, for example:

```
if ([[RowsArr objectAtIndex:section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    return [[RowsArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Once you do this, you'll also get an issue with

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

as this is also assuming you'll get an array.

Change the line:

```
cell.Label.text = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

for:

```
cell.Label.text = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] 
    ? [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
    : [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

and it'll handle both cases.

EDIT: Not sure where you're getting `sections` from, so you may need to change that last one to:

```
cell.Label.text = [[RowsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] 
    ? [[RowsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
    : [RowsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Comment: This is the problem.. sry @Evil..    Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score..

Comment: If you click the grey check mark beside the answer you should be able to accept it as the answer @RohithSingh

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
[[RowsArr objectAtIndex:section] count];
```

This  `[RowsArr objectAtIndex:section]` returns a string not array , so count can't be applied to a string

Also you send count for `RowsArr` and access `sections` arr in `cellForRow`

Comment: How do you get RowsArr  , I mean post it's relevant init code it may be array of json strings